# Loading spinner inside angularjs ui-select

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ui-select

I'm using AngularJs and [ui-select](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select) and I'd like to use a spinner during the data retrieving from the server.
How can I put a spinner inside the html code? 
This is the actual HTML code

```
<div class="col-md-4 form-group">
    <ui-select theme="bootstrap" multiple
        ng-click="populateFilterFleet()"
        on-select="selectFleet($item, $model)"
        on-remove="deSelectFleet($item, $model)" id="fleet"
        name="fleet" data-ng-model="model.idFleetName"
        data-ng-cloak> <ui-select-match
        placeholder="Select Fleet"> <span
        data-ng-style="$item.color && {'color': '{{$item.color}}' }"><i
        class="fa fa-circle"></i></span> {{$item.fleetName}} </ui-select-match> <ui-select-choices
        repeat="singleFleet in fleets | filter: $select.search">                                
    <div class="row"
        style="border-bottom: 1px dashed lightgrey;">

        <div class="col-md-6">                                              
            <b>{{singleFleet.fleetName}}</b>&nbsp;
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4"></div>
        <div class="col-md-2" data-toggle="tooltip"
            data-placement="left" title="Navigate to fleet">
            <a ng-click="navigateToFleet(singleFleet.idFleetName)"
                class="pull-right"><i
                style="margin-right: 5px; color: black;"
                class="fa fa-external-link"></i></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    </ui-select-choices> <ui-select-no-choice>No Fleet</ui-select-no-choice> </ui-select>
</div>
```

and I would like to add a spinner inside select:

```
<i data-ng-show="true" class="fa fa-spinner fa-pulse fa-3x fa-fw"></i>
<span class="sr-only">Loading...</span></div>
```

With a variable inside an ng-show I can manage the data retrieve from server.

Comment: "and I would like to add a spinner inside select," means inside the drop down (which appears on clicking the select box) or simply on the select box?

Comment: I think is better inside select

Comment: You can use custom css for this, placing the loader icon on top of the select box

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using css, though not the most elegant way. Place the loading icon on top of the select box using css position attribute and use `ng-show` to make it visible \ hidden based on your requirement. Something like:

```
<div class="col-md-4 form-group">

<i data-ng-show="true" class="fa fa-spinner fa-pulse fa-3x fa-fw" style="position: relative; top: 16px; left: 5px; z-index: 100"></i>
<!-- You can correct the top, left values as per your requirement and put this in some class to make your code neat-->
<span class="sr-only">Loading...</span></div> 

<ui-select theme="bootstrap" multiple
    ng-click="populateFilterFleet()"
    on-select="selectFleet($item, $model)"
    on-remove="deSelectFleet($item, $model)" id="fleet"
    name="fleet" data-ng-model="model.idFleetName"
    data-ng-cloak> <ui-select-match
    placeholder="Select Fleet"> <span
    data-ng-style="$item.color && {'color': '{{$item.color}}' }"><i
    class="fa fa-circle"></i></span> {{$item.fleetName}} </ui-select-match> <ui-select-choices
    repeat="singleFleet in fleets | filter: $select.search">                                
<div class="row"
    style="border-bottom: 1px dashed lightgrey;">

    <div class="col-md-6">                                              
        <b>{{singleFleet.fleetName}}</b>&nbsp;
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
    <div class="col-md-2" data-toggle="tooltip"
        data-placement="left" title="Navigate to fleet">
        <a ng-click="navigateToFleet(singleFleet.idFleetName)"
            class="pull-right"><i
            style="margin-right: 5px; color: black;"
            class="fa fa-external-link"></i></a>
    </div>
</div>
</ui-select-choices> <ui-select-no-choice>No Fleet</ui-select-no-choice> </ui-select>
</div>
```

Comment: in this way I should put the spinner on top and if the select show element on top instead of buttom it doesn't work. It should be inside the select

Comment: With the z-index, the spinner will float on top of your select along the z-axis (out the plane of the screen) (provided that you have adjusted the `top:` and `left:` values correspondingly).